# the image uploaded is not stored on the database

Tags: django, python-3.x, imagefield

i'm creating a 'create an account view '  which the user can store his image, name ,lastname ....
on my database the name,lastname... are registred but the image is not stored.why?

> in models.py:

```
from django.db import models

      class information(models.Model):  

              name=models.CharField(max_length=50)

              lastname=models.CharField(max_length=50)

              email=models.CharField(max_length=50)

              password=models.CharField(max_length=50)

              img=models.ImageField(upload_to='media',blank=True)
```

> in forms.py:

```
from app1.models import information

from django import forms

     class create_form(forms.ModelForm):

             class Meta:

                   model=information

                   fields=[
                          'name',
                          'lastname',
                           'email',
                           'password',
                            'img'

    ]
```

> in views.py:

```
    def create_view(request,*args,**kwargs):
           my_form=create_form(request.POST or None)
           if my_form.is_valid():
                my_form.save()
                print(my_form.cleaned_data['img'])**#########print :None**    
                context={"form":my_form}
return render(request,'first create.html',context )
```

> in templates:

```
  <main>
       <section>
              <form action="" method="Post"> {% csrf_token %}     
              {{form.as_p}}
              <input type="submit" value="save"/>
              </form> 
       </section>   
  </main>
```

> url.py

from django.contrib import admin

```
 from django.urls import path

 from app1 import views

 from django.conf import settings

 from django.conf.urls.static import static

      urlpatterns = [
            path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
            path('home/', views.firstview, name='home'),
            path('Create/', views.create_view, name='create'),
            path('home/main/', views.homeview, name='main')
         ]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Please read the docs on file upload https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: You did not include multipart in the HTML form and also did not pass request.FILES to the form in your view

Answer (score 0):

You made two mistakes here. First of all, you need to pass `request.FILES` to the form:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def create_view(request,*args,**kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       my_form=create_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
       if my_form.is_valid():
            my_form.save()
            return redirect('some-view')
    else:
        my_form = create_form()
    context={'form': my_form}
    return render(request,'first create.html', context)
```

and furthermore you need to specify `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `<form>` tag:

```
<main>
       <section>
            <form action="" method="Post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}     
            {{form.as_p}}
            <input type="submit" value="save"/>
        </form> 
    </section>   
</main>
```

Note that you better implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) and thus make a [**`redirect(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) in case of a succesful POST request.